# Multiple network interfaces, routing configuration. IP rule fails (debian based instances)

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, routing, debian-wheezy

I have debian wheezy based instance with 2 network interfaces (Primary, Secondary).
My setup flow:

vim /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

ifup eth1
ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:1e:17:4a:dc:0a  
          inet addr:172.31.7.189  Bcast:172.31.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::81e:17ff:fe4a:dc0a/64 Scope:Link
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:74:e6:54:ba:c9  
          inet addr:172.31.10.172  Bcast:172.31.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::874:e6ff:fe54:bac9/64 Scope:Link
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

Okay, all fine in this point and both private ips (172.31.7.189, 172.31.10.172) is accessible to ping.

echo "200 out" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

```
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
200 out
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
172.31.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.31.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

ip route add default via 172.31.0.1 dev eth1 table out

ip rule add from 172.31.0.0/20 table out

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Now instance is not accessible through ssh.
Please help, what i doing wrong?

My workflow is based an tutorial 
https://www.lisenet.com/2014/create-and-attach-a-second-elastic-network-interface-with-eip-to-ec2-vpc-instance/comment-page-1/#comment-105

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Okay, added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I tried to define ip rule for whole network 172.31.0.0/20, that's wrong.

When i use private ip from secondary network interface all works fine.

```
ip route add default via 172.31.10.172 dev eth1 table out
ip rule add from 172.31.10.172 table out
```

where 172.31.10.172 is private ip from network interface eth1

Instead of "ip rule add from 172.31.0.0/20 table out ..."

P.S. Big thanks to Tomas Nevar